# Understanding Median Frequency Balancing?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, deep-learning, computer-vision

This question is with reference to semantic segmentation.

According to the paper [Predicting Depth, Surface Normals and Semantic Labels with a Common Multi-Scale Convolutional Architecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4734.pdf):

> we weight each pixel by `αc = median freq/freq(c)` where freq(c) is the number of pixels of class c divided by the total number of pixels in images where c is present, and median freq is the median of these frequencies

However, I have some difficulty understanding what the author meant by:

1. "number of pixels of class c". Do they mean the number of pixels of class C in one image or in all images?
2. "The total number of pixels in images where c is present" - Do they mean the total number of pixels for each image is divided by the number of pixels of class c in that same image?
3. "median frequency is the median of these frequencies"

After reading the above, my impression of this concept takes the form of this implementation:

1. For each image, calculate the number of pixels C and divide it by the total number of pixels in the image. This will give you a frequency f_i
2. For each image, compute f_i and then sort it by ascending order, before getting the median frequency. This will give you median_freq
3. To compute freq(c), calculate the total number of c pixels in all images, and divide it by the total number of pixels in all images.
4. Finally, compute each pixel's weight according the formula.

Meaning to say the implementation calculates the median frequency of c, aka class c's presence in each image before dividing it by the average presence of class c in all images.

However, I don't think this implementation causes dominant labels to be weighted less, because if dominant labels are frequently present by the same amount and the mean is not too different from the median, then the weight will be roughly equal to 1. So how does this help in class balancing? Could someone clarify whether my implementation is correct or clarify this concept?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretations is as follows:

1. "number of pixels of class c": Represents the total number of pixels of class c across all images of the dataset.
2. "The total number of pixels in images where c is present": Represents the total number of pixels across all images (where there is at least one pixel of class c) of the dataset.
3. "median frequency is the median of these frequencies": Sort the frequencies calculated above and pick the median.

Possible technique for calculation of frequencies of each class:

```
classPixelCount = [array of class.size() zeros]
classTotalCount = [array of class.size() zeros]

for each image in dataset:
    perImageFrequencies = bincount(image)
    classPixelCount = element_wise_sum(classPixelCount, perImageFrequencies)
    nPixelsInImage = image.total_pixel_count()
    for each frequency in per_image_frequencies:
        if frequency > 0:
            classTotalCount = classTotalCount + nPixelsInImage

return elementwiseDivision(classPixelCount, classTotalCount)
```

If you assume that every image must have every class and every image is of the same size, this approximates to:

```
classPixelCount = [array of class.size() zeros]

for each image in dataset:
    perImageFrequencies = bincount(image)
    classPixelCount = element_wise_sum(classPixelCount, perImageFrequencies)

totalPixels = sumElementsOf(classPixelCount)
return elementwiseDivision(classPixelCount, totalPixels)
```

Finally, to calculate the class weights:

```
    sortedFrequencies = sort(frequences)
    medianFreq = median(frequencies)
    return elementwiseDivision(medianFreq, sortedFrequencies)
```

Answer (score 0):

My implement code like this, and the weird thing is that I can get weight small than 1 in small class. Which could reduce the affect in loss when calculate the small class.

````py
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
path = '*.png'
nb_class = 4
total_freq = [[0, 0] for _ in range(nb_class)]
freq_list = defaultdict(list)
for f in tqdm(glob(path)):
    image = Image.open(f)
    image = np.asarray(image)

    # total pixel in one image
    total_pixel = len(image.flatten())
    for i in range(nb_class):
        # number of pixels of class c
        freq_c_num = len(image[image == i].flatten())
        #  frequency of pixel of class c
        freq_c = freq_c_num * 1.0 / total_pixel
        # where c is present
        if freq_c_num > 0:
            freq_list[i].append(freq_c)
            # number of pixel of class c
            total_freq[i][0] += len(image[image == i].flatten())
            # total pixel
            total_freq[i][1] += total_pixel

for i in range(nb_class):
    # media_freq
    median_freq = np.median(freq_list[i])
    # freq(c)
    tmp = total_freq[i][0] * 1.0 / total_freq[i][1]
    # a_c
    print(i, median_freq / tmp)

```
````

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please explain your code.

Comment: The question was asking what is the appropriate process to implement, not how to code. Is it median within image across classes or is it median across images within classes?

Comment: I think it must be median across the whole dataset, otherwise it is hard to get average weight distribution for each classes. And I test my code, find that it accelerate the network coverage.